# Orient DB - How to delete with a match statement?

Tags: orientdb

Is there a good way to delete using a match statement that uses traversal?

i'm trying a delete statement like this, where it grabs students who belong in classroom 999.  anyway it doesn't seem to work.

```
delete vertex from (select 
from 
(match 
  {class: student, as: student}
  .in(){class: classroom, as: classroom, while:(true), where: (id = 999)}
   return student))
```

This doesn't work as a subquery.

Comment: I figured it out! it needs to be turned into a "node".  Answer below

Answer (score 0):

I originally got it working with a traverse.  Then I noticed it wasn't returning back as a "node".  Notice that i had to "expand" the student returned!

```
delete vertex from (select expand(student)
from 
(match 
  {class: student, as: student}
  .in(){class: classroom, as: classroom, while:(true), where: (id = 999)}
  return student))
```